# Best way to check if pointer is initialized

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a way to check if pointer was initialized? I have a struct that cointain array of pointers

```
typedef struct foo
{
    int* ptr1;
    int* ptr2;
    int* ptr2;
    ...
    int* ptr100;
}
```

and then my code is assigning adresses to those pointers (inside loop). But before adress is assigned i want to check if pointer is already containing adress. I know that i can initliazie every pointer with `NULL` and then check this with:

```
if(ptr1 == NULL)
    do something
```

But is there way to write something similiar but without initialization of `ptr`?

Comment: You could `memset` the `struct` right after you declare it.

Comment: No. If the struct is allocated on the stack or heap, the contents will be random. If it is in BSS (a global var), it will be zero initialised, but I'm assuming it probably won't be in your case.

Comment: That is not an array of pointers, those are 100 pointer members.

Comment: I dont believe there is a way to do. you have to manage this with yourself. if you dont initialise a pointer, it can point a same type of data that pointer's one, and this can lead application to fatal errors. in your case, you can find always an integer in heap. so you can always get an integer from a initialized or not initialized pointer

Comment: "*Best way to check if pointer is initialized*" review your code, the only way, BTW.

Comment: "*...  array of pointers ...*" the code you show does not define any array.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An uninitialized variable can contain any value. Therefore, it is not possible to find out if a variable is uninitialized as it can look just like an already initialized variable. The only way to make sure that a variable is initialized is to explicitly write a value (for example, `NULL`) to it as you already noted in your question.

Comment: It's even undefined behaviour testing from an uninitialised variable, thus any try to "check" it for being uninitialised would yield UB.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a `struct` that contains array of pointers [...] is there way to write something similar but without initialization of `ptr`?

No.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626617/694576